# R Shiny: How to output `getwd()`

Tags: r, shiny

Is there something like a working directory when deploying an app to shinyapps.io?

In my app directory I keep `ui.r` and `server.r`, as well as another directory for additional scripts (`engine`). What would be the path to that directory when the app is deployed on shinyapps.io?

Comment: What about `paste0(getwd())`?

Comment: Ok, but where does that get printed?

Comment: Wherever you want I guess - what about `print(paste0(getwd())`?

Comment: Ok, so i need a `textOutput`